# Cannot Refer non final variable productIdList

Tags: android, multithreading, arraylist

On**productIdList.add(p.getId());** this line it says Cannot refer non final variable productIdlist inside an inner class defined in a different method.

here is the code:

```
public ArrayList<String> getProductData() {


    ArrayList<String> productIdList = new ArrayList<String>();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            HttpClient httpclient= new DefaultHttpClient();
            GeneralConstans GC = new GeneralConstans();
            // Products will be stated in memory
            HttpPost httpget = new HttpPost(GC.UrlConstants);
            HttpResponse response;
            String result = null;
            try {

                HttpContext ctx = new BasicHttpContext();

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                        2);
                httpget.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,
                        "UTF-8"));

                response = httpclient.execute(httpget, ctx);
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

                if (resEntity != null) {
                    result = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
                    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(result);
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    if (arr.length() > 0) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length(); j++) {
                            Product p = gson.fromJson(arr.getString(j),
                                    Product.class);
                            productIdList.add(p.getId());
                        }                       

                    }

                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                /*if (checkAbortStatus(e.getMessage()) == true) {
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                }*/
            } catch (IOException e) {
                /*if (checkAbortStatus(e.getMessage()) == true) {
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                }*/
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

        private Handler handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }; 

    }).start();
    return productIdList;
```

what is the problem how can i fix it ?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As it says, `productIdList` must be final to be used within an anonymous inner class. Simply declare it as:

```
final ArrayList<String> productIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Also note that:

- your list will be populated *after* it is returned by your method
- ArrayList is not thread safe: without appropriate synchronization, it is very possible that the code that calls your method won't see the new products added to your list immediately (or at all).

Comment: i did it but it still says the same thing

Comment: @mstfdz It should work - maybe try to clean and build your project?